# Create custom CLPlacemark for RideIntent

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, sirikit, intents-extension

I'm trying to create a custom CLPlacemark using the Intents framework.
I'm importing 'Intents' at files beginning.

I found this solution:

```
let waypointLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 50.00, longitude: 8.00)
let waypointName = "Some Name"

let w1 = CLPlacemark.init(location: waypointLocation,
                                      name: waypointName,
                                      postalAddress: nil)
```

Unfortunately the above code gives me the following error message:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'init(placemark:)'

Any ideas what's wrong?

Documentation:

- init(location:name:postalAddress:) https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clplacemark/2132103-init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By subclassing CLPlacemark it is possible to use the *Intents* frameworks protocol ***init(location:name:postalAddress)***.

Somewhere in your project:

```
class MyPlacemark: CLPlacemark {}
```

Your code to create a custom CLPlacemark:

```
let placeLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 50.00, longitude: 8.00)
let placeName = "Some name"
let customPlacemark = MyPlacemark(location: w1Location, name: w1Name, postalAddress: nil)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still get the same error :( What Frameworks to you import? I tried CoreLocation and Intents... Still the error :(

Answer (score 21):

Just found out that in iOS 12 / Xcode 10 you also have to include the Contacts framework, as the postaladdress param has the class CNPostalAddress required for this initializer

```
import Intents
import Contacts
```

Comment: Would never have found out if it weren't for your comment!

Answer (score -1):

You need to use

```
init(location:name:postalAddress);
```

The placemarkWithLocation call is objective-C not swift hence why it is throwing that error message.

In the documentation you will see a language selection on the right hand side. `init(location:name:postalAddress` is the swift call you will need to create a new place mark.